# what is the best way to create a global variable in React

Tags: reactjs

So I have created the variable as follows...

Creating a global variable as `i`:
[image]

Access the variable:
[image]

Comment: Please use code snippets, do not use images for code.

Answer (score 1):

Context is the best way, Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

IMO, if it's static/constant I think your way is doing fine. In fact you can create a separate file when it's becoming bigger.

But if it's mutable, use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context).

And if it's sensitive credentials like API keys or you want the data to be different for development and staging, you could write it in .env file. [Adding ENV in React](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)